# React Js: why is process.env.REACT_APP_GA_ID undefined only when in production (netlify)

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

In development I get valid data from process.env.REACT_APP_GA_ID, but when I push to production, I get "undefined" why?

Comment: What production environment are you using? This question could use more details.

Comment: netlify is what i use